# DreamWeaver generates mysql queries instead of mysqli queries

Tags: mysql, mysqli, dreamweaver

I am working with dreamweaver CC and WampServer Version 2.5 Apache Version : 2.4.9 and PHP Version : 5.5.12.
when I creat the connecttion and queries using dreamweaver I get all in the deprecated form mysql instead of mysqli.
the connection string generated by dreamweaver is

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_explorecalifornia = "localhost";
$database_explorecalifornia = "explorecalifornia";
$username_explorecalifornia = "root";
$password_explorecalifornia = "pass";
$explorecalifornia = mysql_pconnect($hostname_explorecalifornia, $username_explorecalifornia, 
$password_explorecalifornia) or trigger_error (mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

if I change the mysql_pconnect to mysqli_pconnect it break the string.

and the message:
Deprecated: mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\dwwithphp\Connections\explorecalifornia.php on line 9

is there a way to configuer Dreamweaver to generate mysqli queries instead of mysql???

In php.ini at the [windows extentions] I have

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

and in [MySQLi]

```
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
```

thanks

Dov

Comment: Based on adobe forums, this is not possible, without purchasing a third party extension: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1554705 . Adobe **may** update dreamweaver, but dont count on it, i doubt it is used much nowadays.

Comment: That said, if you are stuck with it, depreciated is not that same as removed - if you turn off warnings on your server, it will still work

Comment: I wouldn't trust *any* database code that DreamWeaver emits, so trash it all and write it correctly using something more modern. At the very least [use PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). Even better would be to use a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and do it properly rather than cobbling it together from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Dreamweaver not support mysqli extension
But you can install Dreamweaver extension for using mysqli with Dreamweaver.
For example **MySQLi Database Connector** (https://mysqli.dwthai.com/) extension for Dreamweaver or etc.